# Filtering List of Dict based of a list of keys in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to filter a list of dict based on another list of keys. See the below sample.

```
# Input list of dict
lst_dict=[{'TABLE_NAME':'TEST1','COLUMN_NAME':'TEST_COLUMN','COLUMN_DATA_TYPE': 'varchar'},
        {'TABLE_NAME': 'TEST1', 'COLUMN_NAME': 'TEST_COLUMN2', 'COLUMN_DATA_TYPE': 'varchar'}, 
        {'COLUMN_DATA_TYPE': 'varchar','TABLE_NAME': 'TEST2','COLUMN_NAME': 'TEST_COLUMN1'}]
# Key List
key_lst = ['TABLE_NAME','COLUMN_NAME']
```

My expected output:

```
[{'TABLE_NAME': 'TEST2', 'COLUMN_NAME': 'TEST_COLUMN1'}, {'TABLE_NAME': 'TEST1', 'COLUMN_NAME': 'TEST_COLUMN'}, {'TABLE_NAME': 'TEST1', 'COLUMN_NAME': 'TEST_COLUMN2'}]
```

I wrote the below code but it is only returning only 1 dict in the list instead of 3. (as per my example)

```
new_list = [{k:v for i in lst_dict for k,v in i.items() if k in key_lst}]
```

I am not sure where I am wrong.. Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have written `new_list`, it looks like you expect it to be a list comprehension, but it is only a list containing a single item, which is a dict comprehension. You probably want to move the iterator over `lst_dict` out of the dictionary and into the list. It should look like this:

```
new_list = [{k:v for k,v in i.items() if k in key_lst} for i in lst_dict]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use *list comprehension* with *dict comprehension* as:

```
>>> my_list = [{key: sub_dict.get(key) for key in key_lst} for sub_dict in lst_dict]
# using "dict.get('key')" in case key is not present in sub dicts in example 
>>> my_list
[{'TABLE_NAME': 'TEST1', 'COLUMN_NAME': 'TEST_COLUMN'}, {'TABLE_NAME': 'TEST1', 'COLUMN_NAME': 'TEST_COLUMN2'}, {'TABLE_NAME': 'TEST2', 'COLUMN_NAME': 'TEST_COLUMN1'}]
```

where `lst_dict` and `key_lst` are holding the values mentioned in the question.

The issue with your attempt is that you are not creating separate `dict` for the sub dicts in your list.

Comment: Got there seconds before me. +1